# Mips how to count unique numbers in an integer

Tags: c, c++11, assembly, mips

Hello I am translating this C code over to MIPS and I am running into a little road block. This program is supposed to count unique digits in an integer. What I am having trouble at is the "IF statement" in the while loop. I can't seem to get my MIPS code to do that C operation.

C code:

```
    while(user > 0) {
       digit = 1 << (user % 10);
       if(!(store & digit)) {
          store += digit;
          count++;
       }
       user /= 10;
     }
```

MIPS code:

```
    WhileLoop:
       #while(user > 0)
       blez $t0, Exit

       #$t3 = user % 10
       div $t3, $t0, 10

       #get remainder
       mfhi $s0

       #move remainder to $t0
       move $t3, $s0

       #$t6 = 1
       li $t6, 1

       #$t8 = 1 << (user % 10)
       sllv $t8, $t6, $t3

       #$t4 = store& digit
       and $t4, $t7, $t8

       #!(store& digit)
       bne $t4, 0, ExitIf

       #store += digit
       add $t7, $t7, $t8

       #count++
       addi $t9, $t9, 1

       ExitIf:
          div $t0, $t0, 10

          #get the quotient
          mflo $s1

          move $t0, $s1

          j WhileLoop
```

Comment: To count unique decimal digits, you probably want a histogram, or a sort.  Or CountingSort / histogram where you just store a `1` instead of load+increment+store because you don't care how many times you see the same digit.  You could even use a bitmap instead of an array, if you have efficient `map |= 1<<digit` like x86 `bts`, and if you have efficient popcount (like x86 `popcnt`) to count set bits when you're done.

Comment: Note that you are overwriting `$t7` which is your `store`. That might not correspond to whatever else the code is doing (but we can't tell because you did not show it).

Comment: `bne` against `$zero` is `if($t7 != 0) goto target`.  IDK if you're considering fall-through or taken in asm as entering the C `if` body.  But possibly you got the `!` backwards.

Comment: Oh, you are using the bitmap idea I suggested.  Your C doesn't declare types for any of those variables but I assume `uint32_t`.  Anyway, as Jester and Erik point out, you're destroying the old value of `store` so Erik's answer does answer your question.  Use a separate tmp reg.  Looks like most of t1..t5 are unused, at least at that point.

Comment: Note that `|=` is `or` not `add`.  But since you've already checked that the bit isn't set, `add` is safe.  (And since you're working in base 10, not base 32, `add` can't have signed overflow and fault.)

Comment: Hi Peter thank you for the help. Sorry Stackoverflow doesn't like it when I post too much code so i'll clarify any confusion here. I li the store and digit to zero in my main. I assumed I overwrite the store and digit because i needed to update it in my while loop

Comment: Overwriting `store` with `store&digit` clears all the *other* bits, so you no longer eliminate duplicates.  Single-step it in a debugger.  Also, make sure you notify people when you reply to their comments, by including @username in your comment.

Answer (score 2):

Your MIPS code is doing:

```
store &= digit
```

Are  you sure you want to update `store` — that's not what your C code is doing.

Also, as your C code example is incomplete (as is the assembly), we cannot tell if you properly reversed the condition for the assembly version.

In C, an `if ( a ) then-part` needs to be `if (! a) goto skip; then-part; skip: ;` in assembly.